# Overlay text on top of a Recharts chart

Tags: recharts

I'm trying to add static a piece of text (not related to the data being displayed) in the lower-right corner of a Recharts chart.

I could hack together some CSS & HTML to get the text there from a neighboring DOM element, but I'd rather do it using the recharts API.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<XAxis>` component can take a prop called `label`.

```
<XAxis 
   dataKey="name" 
   label={{ value: 'random text', position: 'insideBottomRight', offset: -20 }} 
/>
```

The combination of position and offset would lead to a solution you want.
Check the [docs](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Label) and a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dxe1vwho/1/).

Comment: That puts it below the chart though. Can't figure out in-chart text either.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<text>` element inside a rechart chart to add arbitrary text in any position you wish.

For instance:

```
import {
    RadialBarChart,
    RadialBar,
    Legend,
    Tooltip,
} from 'recharts'

const data = [
    {
        name: 'Target (5%)',
        uv: 5,
        pv: 4567,
        fill: '#777',
    },
    {
        name: 'Growth %',
        uv: 8.3,
        pv: 2400,
        fill: '#22AA22',
    },
]

const RadialBarChart01 = () => {
    return (
        <RadialBarChart
            width={400}
            height={400}
            innerRadius='70%'
            outerRadius='120%'
            data={data}
            startAngle={180}
            endAngle={0}
        >
            <RadialBar
                label={{ fill: '#FFF', position: 'insideStart' }}
                background
                clockWise={true}
                dataKey='uv'
            />
            <text
                x='50%'
                y='50%'
                dy={+12}
                style={{ fontSize: 48, fontWeight: 'bold', fill: '#22AA22' }}
                width={200}
                scaleToFit={true}
                textAnchor='middle'
                verticalAnchor='middle'
            >
                8.3%
            </text>
            <text
                x='50%'
                y='60%'
                style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold', fill: '#777' }}
                width={200}
                scaleToFit={true}
                textAnchor='middle'
                verticalAnchor='middle'
            >
                Target: 5%
            </text>
            <Legend
                iconSize={20}
                width={120}
                height={100}
                layout='vertical'
                verticalAlign='bottom'
                align='center'
            />
            <Tooltip />
        </RadialBarChart>
    )
}

export default RadialBarChart01
```

See result in image capture:

[image]